# Working on a sas mixins to attach the values based on the margin-position

Tags: html, css, sass, mixins, scss-mixins

Hi Iam writing a mixins where I want to attach the values based on the margin position I have come far this not sure how to move forward.

```
@mixin margin ($value, $positions...){
  @each $position in $positions {
    margin-#{$position}: $value;
  }
}

.margin-top {
  @include margin(10px, top);
}
.margin-multiple {
  @include margin(10px, top, left, right);
}
```

In my `magin-multiple` selector if I pass three different values it should attach to the respective margin position. For instance if I include `@include margin(10px, 8px, 5px, top, left, right);` my expected output is as follows

```
.margin-multiple {
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-left: 8px;
   margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For me, this is working as expected: `.margin-top{margin-top:10px}.margin-multiple{margin-top:10px;margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px}`

Comment: Updated my question @I'mLu please check.

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution:

```
@mixin margin ($values, $positions) {
    @for $i from 1 through length($values) {
        margin-#{nth($positions, $i)}: nth($values, $i);
    }
}
```

It takes **lists** as parameters, so you call it like:

```
.margin-multiple {
    @include margin(10px 8px 5px, top left right)
}
```

which results in the expected output:

```
.margin-multiple {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Always make sure to use lists of the same length for *values* and *positions*!

Comment: This answer only works when equal number values and position is passed. I need a solution something like if I pass a single value the system should understand its common for all the position as well.

Comment: @Benjamin try using **@if** to check the length of *values*. But what should happen if you pass 2 values and 3 positions? By the way, I think this goes clearly to far from here. It's the purpose of SASS/SCSS to make CSS more easy and readible. In my eyes, you should just write `margin: 10px 8px 5px 0;`.

Comment: If I pass just 2 values and 3 position it should throw me an error.

Comment: As I mentioned, you *can* do this with **@if**-conditions. But I would strongly advise against it.